# setting cache-control header

Tags: asp.net, meta-tags

I have to set cache-control header to "no-cache, no-store".For this i am using 
html meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

in the  tag  of the web page.
I inspected in firebug. In spite of having cache-control to desired one it is having as "private".
I am using ASP.NET framework.
Any idea why this is failing?

Comment: Do you mean the HTTP headers when you say "header section of the web page"?

Answer (score 2):

from code behind you add:

```
 Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Comment: I specifically had a problem where in IE (only) the content of Colorbox iframes was being cached under the private setting and this cleared up the problem. Thanks!